# Transferring data from Excel to SQL multiple indexed tables

Tags: sql, excel, indexing, ssis

I have like 20 tables and one general table in SQL. That main table has indexes in in its columns. Using these indexes I create a view by getting the data from other 20 tables.

My question would be what would be the most efficient way to create a process of updating all of those tables accordingly using an Excel source. It should be future proof (new excel data being inputted once a month e.g.).

If it is a SSIS package how would it look, maybe you have any examples of something similar?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I for one do *not* like SSIS.  I find it a pain to troubleshoot, but for some tasks it's fine.  If I were you I would:

- Use the `data import wizard` from within Microsoft SQL Studio to import the Excel file.

[image]

- Simply get the data into a `staging` table in SQL.
- You'll have the option to save this as an SSIS package, good for automation
- Now, write a pile of SQL to sort and update the data as you wish. Perhaps make a series of stored procedures
- Create a job in SQL that runs your package, and then runs each stored procedure

Writing a solution in this fashion will allow you to troubleshoot each step and make reporting easy.  You *can* just do the whole thing is SSIS but like I said, I'm not a fan of that tool.  I like my code on the command line as much as possible for troubleshooting :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this [app from windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/spreadsheet-into-sql-data/9nh0w51xxqrm?cid=msft_web_search) to convert Excel into SQL script.
Then send script to our DBA.